# automated changing file names every time you run the program

Tags: python, python-3.5

Hi I want my program to change filenames every time I run a program. 
And I also want the files to be saved in a seperate folder. 
Possible unique names could either be a counter that adds a number to the name for example ( xml_1, xml_2, xml_3 and so on ) or the date when the file is created.

This is what I have so far

```
with open("new_xml_1.xml","w+") as f:
   for index, row in df.iterrows():
      xml_1 = (csv_to_xml(row))
      print(xml_1)
      f.write(xml_1)
```

I was thinking something like this

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
currentDate = str(now.month) + "_" + str(now.day) + "_" + str(now.year)

file_output = os.path.join(r"C:\bla\bla\path\to\folder\filename_" + currentDate)
```

Maybe there is a simpler Solution but I cant find it.

So thanks for any help, since I am new to python so any experience I can get is helpful to me.

Comment: Do you need the unique names to make sense to you, or are any unique names fine? If a nonsense "counter" is OK, check out `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile`.

Comment: They should indeed make sense since other people should get access to the file stored inside

Comment: altough thanks for your help

Comment: are you running this on mac? or windows?

Comment: i am runnning on windows using jupyter lab

Answer (score 1):

To create a unique file name every time your program is run, you can use the [`NamedTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile) class of the built-in `tempfile` module. The constructor has several optional parameters, including `prefix`, `suffix` and `dir` which allow you to produce a file name recognisable to people who need to access this file.

Possible usage could be:

```
import tempfile                                                                 

f = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(prefix="myfilename_", suffix=".txt", dir=".", delete=False)                  
print(f.name)
```

Output on Mac:

```
/Users/user/Documents/myfilename_8oivjhql.txt
```

Note that I have set `delete` to `False` to ensure that it is not deleted when your program closes the file.